# Convert a ggplot2 heatmap to the relative plotly heatmap with plot_ly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Hello I have the dataset below:

```
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD","ASDAD","XCVXCVX","EQWESDA","DASDADS","SDASDASD","DADADASD","sdaadfd","DFSD","SADADDAD","SADDADADA","DADSADSASDWQ","SDADASDAD","ASD","DSADD")
panel<-c("growth","growth","growth","growth","big","big","big","small","small","small","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf2<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf3<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf4<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf5<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf11<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf21<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf31<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf41<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf51<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
Gene_states22<-data.frame(gene_symbol,panel,ASDDA,ASDDb,ASDDAf,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf2,ASDDAf3,ASDDAf4,ASDDAf5,ASDDA1,ASDDb1,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf11,ASDDAf21,ASDDAf31,ASDDAf41,ASDDAf51)
```

and I have created a ggplot2 heatmap with:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
g <- melt(Gene_states22, id.vars = c("gene_symbol","panel"))
p1<-ggplot(g, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
                                                     colour = "grey50") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue","black","yellow","green","brown"))+
  facet_grid(~panel,switch = "x",scales ="free_x")+
  labs(title = "Heatmap",x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
  theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                             size = 14, 
                             face = "bold"), 
        axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                  size = 16, 
                                  face = "bold", 
                                  color = "black"), 
        axis.text = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                 size = 11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 10,hjust = 10),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside")
p1
```

then I converted it to plotly with `ggplotly()`

```
ggplotly(p1)%>%
  layout( autosize = F, width = 1350, height = 600,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                                                                     font = list(family = "sans serif", 
                                                                                 size = 9, 
                                                                                 color = "black")))
```

The problem is that some of the features of ggplot2 like element_text() for example which adjusts the labels distances from the graph do not work properly in plotly and I would like to create the same heatmap exclusively with plotly and `plot_ly()` but I have small experience on this and cannot achieve this 100%.

Comment: Your `ggplot2`plot gives me this `Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)` and I don't see the plot.

Comment: Does anybody else get this error?Because to me it works fine.

Comment: I am using `reshape2_1.4.3,  plotly_4.7.1.9000,  ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`.

Comment: I got exactly the same versions. Do you recreate the data frame without problem?

Comment: This is very odd because I can't see `p1`, but `ggplotly(p1)` works!

Comment: So you cannot see the heatmap at all? Do you believe that you could convert it to plotly with plot_ly()?

Comment: I can see the heatmap. It looks like plotly does not have discrete color for the heatmap. Instead of `facet`, you could use `subplot`.

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: This one is overall, `plot_ly(data = g,
  x = ~ gene_symbol, y = ~variable,
  z = ~as.numeric(as.factor(value)), type = "heatmap"
)`. You could split your df into 4 (by panel), and build 4 small heatmaps and use subplot to combine them.